# how to check if bond array is Null or empty in iphone sdk?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to check if my `array` is empty or `null` and `not null` or not empty. Below is some sample code I have written. Can you tell me if this is on the right track?

```
  /// first time get data there
{
    Bonds = Null;
    User =     {
        DOB = "12/09/1988";
        about = "test about";
        city = CA;
    };
    success = True;
}
////////Second time get data there   
{
    Bonds =     (
                {
            DOB = "12/09/1988";
            about = "";
            city = CA;
    },
            {
        DOB = "12/09/1988";
        about = "";
        city = CA;
    }
);
User =     {
    DOB = "12/09/1988";
    about = about;
    city = CA;
};
success = True;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                 @try
                 {
                    if([Your_array objectAtIndex:int]== (id)[NSNull null] || [Your_array objectAtIndex:int]==0)
                     {
                         // if index get null
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         //your code if array index is not null 
                     }
                 }

                 @catch (NSException * e)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"NSException");
                 }
```

Comment: its really work so just try it your array will not bound by using  this and your app is not crash..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to check for an empty array in Objective C (you mentioned iPhone SDK but not the language- Swift or Objective C) you can simply check the count.

```
if ([myArray count]==0) // the array is empty
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(![Bonds isKindOfClass:[NSArray Class]]) // for non nil array and
    if([Bounds firstObject]) //to check if array having at least one element
```

Answer (score 0):

if array is not nil, and if not - check if it is not empty.

```
if (!array || !array.count){
     ......
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(array && ![array isEqual:[NSNull null]] && [array count] > 0)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this

```
if ((NSNull*) Bonds !=[NSNull null] && Bonds!=nil && [array count] > 0)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!array || !array.count){
     ......
    }
```